# Nuxt universal app. Vuex store on server side is cached between requests irrespective of the user's machine

Tags: vuejs2, nuxt.js, vuex

I have observed the following behaviour in production instances of Nuxt Universal Apps:

---

**Given** "User A" makes a page request that accesses nuxt's server side **and** a server-side method such as `asyncData` dispatches state changes in the process

**if** "User B" *on a separate machine* makes a request to the server via a server-side method for the state data that "User A" changed earlier,

**then** "User B" will be able to access that data.

---

**ergo** nuxt is treating Vuex as a single store on the server with no distinction between different callers.

Is there a configurable way to prevent this behaviour and insist that each user is only able to access data associated with their local machine?

[EDIT]
as requested, this is an approximation of the store's index.js

```js
import { omit } from 'lodash'
import Vue from 'vue'

// we drafted some methods for automatically generating generic getters and setter-mutators.  
// Also, default actions are setup where a list of names are given, that automatically commit to generic setter mutators. 
// see comments in the code below...
import {
  autoMapGetters,
  autoMapMutations,
  autoMapActions
} from '~/libs/autoMap'

const _state = {
  centre: { id: -1 },
  devEmail: 'foo@bar.com',
  barApiUrl: process.env.FooUrl + '/foo',
  barDownloadImg: process.env.FooUrl + process.env.FooImg,
  barDownloadLockImg: process.env.FooUrl + process.env.FoobarDownloadLockImg,
  FooLoginUrl: process.env.FooUrl + '/foo/auth',
  FooBarUrl: process.env.FooUrl + '/bar',
  FooUrl: process.env.FooUrl,
  loading: false,
  warnings: {}
}

export default {
  state: () => (_state),

  getters: autoMapGetters(_state, {
    foo: (state) => state.foo.someSpecialProperty ? { foo: 'I am different' } : {},
    etc: (state) => etc
    // For example, autoMapGetters will set:
    // centre: (state) => state.centre
  }), 

  mutations: autoMapMutations(_state, {
    clearWarning (_state, key) { Vue.delete(_state.warnings, key) },
    clearWarnings (_state) { _state.warnings = {} },
    setWarning (_state, { key, value }) { _state.warnings[key] = value }
    // For example, a autoMapMutations will generate:
    // setCentre (state, centre) { state.centre = centre }  
  }),

  actions: autoMapActions(_state, {
    // special action, launched server-side ------------------------------------
    nuxtServerInit ({ state, commit, getters, dispatch }, { params }) {
      dispatch('foo-module/resetAll')
      dispatch('foo-module/resetMainInformation')
    },
    
    // Normal actions ----------------------------------------------------------
    clearCentre ({ commit }) { commit('setCentre', { id: -1 }) },
    setCentre ({ commit, dispatch }, centre) {
      commit('setCentre', omit(centre, 'user'))
      dispatch('bar-module/setUser', centre.user)
    },
    clearWarning ({ commit }, key) { commit('clearWarning', key) },
    clearWarnings ({ commit }) { commit('clearWarnings') },
    setWarning ({ commit }, { key, value }) { commit('setWarning', { key, value }) }
    // For Example, autoMapActions will generate:
    // setLoading ({ commit }, value) { commit('setLoading', value) }
  }, [
    'loading',
    'warnings'
  ])
}
```

Comment: Can you share your store index.js?

Comment: Let me see if I can draft an imitation... it's a production store you see...

Comment: I just wanted to see if you’ve exported the store as a function, not an object. If you export as an object you’d get the exact behaviour you’re describing, which isn’t a nuxt bug as such— just a common gotcha when coming from Vue to nuxt.

Comment: ah! Is that so! perhaps that's it!! So if I should export the store as a function for index.js? Is that correct?

Comment: If that is a common gotcha, I'm blown away by how little info there is on said gotcha! even the docs make no reference to it!

Comment: They even have points at which you can easily infer that `export default` is acceptable on their own documentation! see the code block in the below: https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#the-nuxtserverinit-action

Comment: I've just checked the docs, seems they have indeed updated it to reflect this "gotcha". "Your state value should always be a function to avoid unwanted shared state on the server side." https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#modules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion it isn't very clear in the docs**, but you need to export the store as a function (with an explicit or implicit return)- not an object. Exporting as a function creates a new store on the server, whereas exporting as a plain object will always return that same object.

**EDIT: Seems the [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/2.x/directory-structure/store#modules) have been updated to highlight this now.

Here's the example in the docs:

```
export const state = () => ({
  list: []
})
```

Notice the `()` wrapping the object literal?

Try adjusting your code with this in mind (pseudo code example, I'm sure you'll figure out passing the state into your automap methods!)

```
import { omit } from 'lodash'
import Vue from 'vue'

import {
  autoMapGetters,
  autoMapMutations,
  autoMapActions
} from '~/libs/autoMap'

export const state = () => ({
  centre: { id: -1 },
  devEmail: 'foo@bar.com',
  barApiUrl: process.env.FooUrl + '/foo',
  barDownloadImg: process.env.FooUrl + process.env.FooImg,
  barDownloadLockImg: process.env.FooUrl + process.env.FoobarDownloadLockImg,
  FooLoginUrl: process.env.FooUrl + '/foo/auth',
  FooBarUrl: process.env.FooUrl + '/bar',
  FooUrl: process.env.FooUrl,
  loading: false,
  warnings: {}
})

export const getters = {
   // ... your automap method here
}

export const mutations = {
  // ... your automap method here
}

export const actions = {
  // nuxtServerInit etc ...
}
```